# What is a python field relative to other Python-based language constructs?

Tags: python, openbabel

I'm using the Python OpenBabel package (https://openbabel.org/docs/current/UseTheLibrary/PythonDoc.html) and stepping through my code using the PyCharm IDE. I'm running into a problem, but I must understand the terminology used in PyCharm and the Python Language before I can fix the problem. I'm finding some of the terminology confusing.

This is the code. On the website, this construct works, but when I tried to perform this operation, it doesn't work i.e., the `mol` instance of class `OBMol` does not change, even though it returns `True` (the API docs state that the mol obj changes):

```
from openbabel import openbabel as ob

pdbqtFile = "a string path to a pdbqt file" 
obConversion = ob.OBConversion()
obConversion.SetInAndOutFormats("pdbqt", "pdb")
mol = ob.OBMol()
obConversion.ReadFile(mol, pdbqtFilePath)

# This is where I'm confused
value = mol.AddHydrogens()
```

This is where I'm confused:

In the PyCharm drop-down code suggestion, `mol.AddHydrogens` has a lower-case **f** next to it. Looking this up, it's called a **field**. But if I `print(mol.AddHydrogens)` I get:

<bound method OBMol_AddHydrogens of <openbabel.openbabel.OBMol; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'OpenBabel::OBMol *' at 0x0000022DDB9D5B40> >>

Notice the word **method** in that output. I understand what that is, but it's been referred to as a field in the IDE. If this is a method, and it states it is, why does PyCharm not have a **m** in the drop-down suggestions? What is a field, and how does it differ from a method? I have a feeling, the answer will have something to do with this method being **bound**.

Comment: Are you sure *f* stands for _field_ and not **function**?

Comment: @deceze Yep – PyCharm shows `m` for methods.

Comment: @deceze what I've found: c - class, f - field, F - function, m - method, p - parameter, P - property, and v - variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple example:

[image]

shows `Foo.derp` to be a field (which it is), but the value is definitely callable (since it is just `print` after all), and `print(Foo.derp)` will print `<built-in function print>`.

You'd need to look at how openbabel is implemented to figure out why PyCharm is showing you a `f`ield – but in the grand scheme of things, it doesn't really matter much.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Thank you for explaining what I'm seeing.